# Bootstrap always valid under asymptotic Normality?

Tags: econometrics, causal-inference

If an estimator is known to have an asymptotically normal distribution, is that sufficient for the bootstrap to be valid?

It seems that is must be, but in 20 minutes of Googling I have come up empty on a proof.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Theorem 2.1 in [Horowitz (2019)](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1809/1809.04016.pdf) is what you are looking for